# Launch iOS app from browser within iframe

Tags: iframe, launch, ios-universal-links

I try to launch my iOS application from webpage. Either Universal Links or Custom URL Schema works fine only if I use it in top level window of the html document.

If I put the same code into the nested `<iframe>` it fails. Safari just silently ignores everything I tried.

By using Custom URL Scheme I use something like this.

```
window.location = "myapp://launch?param=blablabla";
```

or

```
$("#launch-content").append($('<iframe/>', {
  id: 'launch-frame',
  src: "myapp://launch?param=blablabla",
  width: '100%', height: '100%'
}));
```

By using Universal Links I just put the anchor with such a link.

```
<a href="https://myhost/ios-launch">Launch App</a>
```

In top level window universal link opens the app, but inside the `<iframe>` it, unfortunately, just opens a page.

I search the web and can't find any reliable information on how to deal with iframes in this context. Is it possible to achieve the goal somehow or I just waste time and restriction is intentionally made by Apple?

Comment: did you resolve the problem?

Comment: no, I got rid of irame

Comment: Still a problem. If you do `target=_blank`, it'll work if you have the app installed. But then it won't work if you DON'T have it installed. If you don't add `target=_blank` it'll work with app not-installed.

Comment: @Siverchen any luck?